# PHP - $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] - how to store once, not again when a form submission occurs

Tags: php, referer

In PHP, how would I go about storing the variable "backurl"? (retrieved as shown below at the bottom - when the following constraints need to apply)

- The variable "backurl" is storing the last php script viewed.
- On first execute the variable "backurl" is stored and works correctly
- When a form is submitted through $_GET or $_POST within that script, the variable will update as the previous URL has changed. (I don't want this to happen)

i.e.
FROM -> TO (actual outcome - desired outcome)
page1.php -> page2.php (link goes to page1.php - as intended)

page2.php -> page2.php?test=yes (link goes to page2.php - I want it to go back to page1.php)

If anyone has any suggestions of how to do this, thank you very much!

```
$backurl =  $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use sessions

```
<?php

session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['backurl'])){
$_SESSION['backurl'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}
?>
$_SESSION['backurl']; //contains the back url;
```

and if you nee to unset the backurl:

```
unset($_SESSION['backurl']);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I would vote you up but I need 15 rep points to do so! :(

Answer (score 0):

Set the *backurl* in `session` and access it whenever & however you needed in *page2.php*

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. One could be updating your backurl only if the script page is different, using session.

e.g. (untested):

```
session_start();

if( $_SEVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] != $_SESSION['lastpage'] ){
    $_SESSION['backurl'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}
```

This way, you'll only update the backurl when you call a different php page, leaving it unchanged when you go to the same page with different parameters (based on your example).

Adapt the code to your needs.